# PHP how to print result from SQL database?

Tags: php

i am new to this community so i will try to make it clear as possible. I have to write a code which will select Id for the DataBase and then it's column data will be shown. The users is the one who selects the Id so it will be dynamic. So far i got this:

```
<?php
 $i = $rep['prnId'];
      $prnline = sqlSelectSingle("SELECT * FROM PrintMarginTypes WHERE prnId = ?", Array($i));
       $prnline = sqlExec("UPDATE ResponsiblePersons SET repPrintId = repPrintId + 1 WHERE repId = ?");
$prnline["prn"]
?>
```

P.S tnx in advance!

Comment: http://php.net/echo ?

Comment: Seems like you are using some type of library, Where are the functions `sqlSelectSingle()` and `sqlExec()` defined?

Comment: `echo $prnline['prn'];`

Comment: In another file. That is the code which define's them:                              {function setPrinter ($fpJtbId){
 
  $ar = sqlExec("
  
  
   UPDATE
    ResponsiblePersons
   SET
    repPrintId = ?
   FROM
    ResponsiblePersons
   INNER JOIN
    PrintMarginTypes
   ON
    ResponsiblePersons.repId = PrintMarginTypes.prnId

   WHERE 
    PrintMarginTypes.prnId = ? AND 
    repName = ? 
   
    "
  );  
  
  
  return $ar;
 };}